# Using SIMBL to install Afloat

Tags: macos, window-manager, simbl

I have the plugin for Afloat, I just don't know how to start it up.

I've disabled SIP. I can't find the app in Applications and the window options haven't changed at all.

Am I supposed to run the app somehow?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What version of **macOS** are you running? I see the _window_ you are showing is in _dark mode_ and as such I do not believe **Afloat** is supported on any version of **macOS** that supports _dark mode_. In other words, I think **macOS High Sierra** it the only version of **macOS** it works on, as well as some versions of **Mac OS X/OS X**.

Comment: SIMBL is dead, dead, DEAD.  And was never worth much even when it wasn't.